# unable to set existing text view from xml to textview array

Tags: android, textview

I have 2 TextView in my Xml file and I have set them in TextView Array. How Can I access them based on the index.

Please Help me regarding this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Textview a,s,d,f,g,h;
intialize all;
TextView[] text_arrays;

text_array = new TextView[]{a,s,d,f,g,h};
```

now do what you want like

```
text_array[0].setText("Text View One);
text_array[1].setText("Text View two);
text_array[5].setText("Text View six);
```